# Is it the circular dependency?

Tags: python, software-design

It's said that circular dependencies are bad and anti-patterns. So my question is what's wrong with the code below? Is it an example of circular dependency at all? The code is in python pseudocode but should be understood.

```
class Manager:
    _handlers = []

    def on_config(self):
        # do something...
        # and notify about "event"
        for handler in self._handlers:
            handler()

    def add_change_handler(self, handler):
        self._handlers.append(handler)

    def get_value(self):
        return some_value

class Consumer:
    def __init__(self, manager):
        self._manager = manager
        self._manager.add_change_handler(self._on_event)

    def _on_change(self):
        print('Got event')

    def do_something(self):
        self._manager.get_value()
```

So: Consumer gets manager to:

- get_value from it
- to register for litening on change event

The argument from guys that are against that solution is that it's better to create other class, that will:

- know about manager and consumer
- listen on config event
- call consumer's on_change handler
- Consumer will use manager only to get_value

Comment: This does not qualify as a *"dependency"*. It's a circular *relationship* perhaps, but not a dependency.

Comment: There is no circular dependency in the code.

Comment: OK, thanks. But is that design flawed? What's wrong with it if it is? Is the proposed at the end solution a better choice?

Answer (score -1):

[Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python). This answer will help you know more about circular imports in python.

This code is not about circular dependency.
You can also regard this situation as a trade between bussinessmans.

```
#!/bin/python
class Businessman:
    _trader_list = []

    def __init__(self, name, goods):
        self.m_name = name
        self.m_goods = goods

    def on_get_goods(self):
        for trader in self._trader_list:
            trader.buy_some(self)

    def add_change_handler(self, handler):
        self._trader_list.append(handler)

    def del_change_handler(self, handler):
        self._trader_list.remove(handler)

    def buy_some(self, from_bussinessman):
        print "{0} will buy some {1}s from {2}".format(
            self.m_name, from_bussinessman.m_goods, from_bussinessman.m_name)

    def get_goods(self):
        print("{0} gets new {1}s.".format(self.m_name, self.m_goods))
        self.on_get_goods()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bob = Businessman('Bob', 'apple')
    jack = Businessman('Jack', 'banana')
    cream = Businessman('Cream', 'rice')
    # Bob notifys Jack and Cream to buy apples when he gets some.
    seller1 = bob
    seller1.add_change_handler(jack)
    seller1.add_change_handler(cream)
    seller1.get_goods()
```

The result is

```
Bob gets new apples.
Jack will buy some apples from Bob
Cream will buy some apples from Bob
```